# Django ckeditor - set width to 100%

Tags: django, ckeditor

I've got a simple django-ckeditor implementation with default settings set as

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': [
            ['Undo', 'Redo',
             '-', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline',
             '-', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor',
             '-', 'Format',
             '-', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt',
             '-', 'Maximize',
             '-', 'Language',
            ],
        ],
        'height': '100%',
        'width': '100%',
        'toolbarCanCollapse': False,
    },
}
```

Within my form I have

```
{{ form.media }}
{{ form.description }}
```

I'm expecting the ckeditor field to cover 100% width but it covers 100% of the menu bar.  How do I get it to cover the available width?

Thanks

Comment: 100% percentage means 100% of the width of its immediate parent element.

Comment: did you check the width of parent node of the ckeditor?

Comment: so I've put it inside a `<div style="min-width:100%">{{ form.description }}</div>` which should set the parent to 100% but this isn't working either (the parent is 100%, but the ckeditor isn't)

Comment: Again, `min-width:100%` to an element means it will stretch to 100% of the width of `its parent element`.

Comment: You can inspect your html in your browser. Scrolling over the elements highlights the width and height. Can you please check and see what width is dedicated to your parent div?

Comment: I've done that.  Width of parent is 100% and the highlighted area is across the whole screen

Comment: This is what I've done which has worked.  I've added `<style>
.django-ckeditor-widget {
    min-width:100% !important;
}
</style>` to the start of the html file which is now providing a full width editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used css to solve it.

```
.django-ckeditor-widget{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: fastest way so far.

Answer (score 10):

In the settings.py

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'height': 'full', 
        'width': 'full', 
    },
}
```

Comment: This should be marked a the correct and proper answer of this post.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Adding this javascript to the template solved my problem.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".django-ckeditor-widget").css("width", "100%")
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

css:

```
.django-ckeditor-widget{
    display: inline !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On setting up an instance of ckeditor you can trigger the **maximize** event like this.

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady',
   function( evt )
   {
     var editor = evt.editor;
     editor.execCommand('maximize');
   });
```

Hope this solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

edit "**admin_change_form_document_ready**" block at ***templates > admin > change_form.html***

```html
{% block admin_change_form_document_ready %}
    <script type="text/javascript"
            id="django-admin-form-add-constants"
            src="{% static 'admin/js/change_form.js' %}"
            {% if adminform and add %}
                data-model-name="{{ opts.model_name }}"
            {% endif %}>
    </script>
    <script>
      setTimeout(function(){
        for (let editor of document.getElementsByClassName('cke_browser_webkit')){
          editor.style.width = '100%';
        }
      }, 500)
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```